# Duplicate one monitor to the other on Windows 7, extend desktop on a third

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a three monitor setup, how can I use monitor 2 for an extended desktop, but duplicate what's on monitor 1 on monitor 3? Monitor 3 has a lower resolution, if that matters.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you have done already. You state "*I have a three monitor setup*", which would lead us to believe the monitors are setup and working, just not the way you would like. Is that correct? Does Windows 7 recognize all the monitors in screen resolution window?

Comment: Sorry, yes, they all work correctly at the resolutions I need them, but it will only give me the option to extend the desktop across all 3, or to duplicate one monitor on the other two.

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on your desktop and then choose Screen resolution, you'll see all your monitors and how they are lined up. Then click on your first monitor and open the dropdown under "Multiple monitors". If it's possible to duplicate your monitors 1 and 2, this will be an option.

It could be that it's not possible to duplicate your monitors. This happens when the monitors are connected to different video cards which are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in a default Windows installation. There are [third-party tools](https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/) that allow this.